# Is it possible to purge concrete custom events from Azure Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I had to push certain events manually and accidentally did it twice. I would like to purge the duplicates. Is it possible at all?

Comment: This allows you to specify filters to use when purging, which may work for your situation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/components/purge

Comment: Please, arrange it as answer, because it seems to work. If you include how to view the status of the operations, that would be terrific.

Comment: So, I started the operation 4 hours ago. The records are still there and the operation is still reported as `Started`. Hope it works.

Comment: @mark, it may take a very long time, maybe some days as per my testing some time ago.

Comment: Wow, That is unexpected somewhat. OK, I will wait.

Comment: @TrevorBrooks, please add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows you to specify filters to use when purging, which may work for your situation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/components/purge

Passing in the operationId Guid will allow you to retreive the status of the purge operation.

For example:  https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/YourSubscriptionId/resourceGroups/YourResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components/YourApplicationInsights/operations/purge-_GuidReturnedbyPURGEoperation?api-version=2015-05-01

Be advised it can take up to 72 hours for the data to completely purge.

Also, here's a good little blog article that has a few more details:  https://sanganakauthority.blogspot.com/2019/06/how-to-delete-or-purge-azure.html